# Why did James Harrington nickname Oliver Cromwell "Lord Achon"

Tags: nicknames

Going back a year or two, was foreaware of the Cromwell nick *"His Noseship"* but not *"Lord Achon"* itself said to be from a character in James Harrington's writings *Oceana*. Haps heedful all the online references bear a slight sundered yet telling spelling "Lord Archon". Anyway, though I have some amazing thoughts anent the aforegone, I would be most grateful to firstly get other input.

Comment: Don't know the answer but, the question is lovely.

Comment: The History site would undoubtedly appreciate this question, and it might attract some interesting answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Commonwealth_of_Oceana) for this book, Harrington's *Commonwealth of Oceana* was first published in in 1656. An examination of the contents of the [1656 edition of the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wt4SZvyCVSwC&pg=PP13&dq=%22oceana%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZouqZtsfgAhXmhVQKHRXSClYQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22Lord%20Achon%22&f=false), discoverable with a Google Books search, yields ten instances of "Lord *Archon*" and no instances of "Lord *Achon*."

It thus seems probable that Harrington intended to name the Cromwell character "Lord Archon"— since *archon* (or rather, αρχων) has the following meaning, according to Liddell & Scott, *An Intermediate Greek-English Lexicon* (1889):

> a ruler, commander, chief, captain

Some subsequent editions may occasionally or consistently have mistyped the name as "Lord *Achon*," but the first edition seems to have gotten it right.

Comment: Thanks to the inputters for the input. Anyone know how I get to WS2's said suggested "History site"?

Comment: @ WS2/Sven Yargs sorry that I did not bother to list the 1887 book "Sobriquets And Nicknames" as my wellspring for the misspelling "Lord Achon" Bytheway, thanks for your input brethren.